# How can i use 'log' inside a src/groovy/ class

Tags: grails, log4j

I'm encountering this error:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:
>   No such property: log for class:
>   org.utils.MyClass

Here's the content of the class:

```
package org.utils

class MyClass {
    int organizationCount = 0

    public int getOrganizationCount(){
        log.debug "There are ${organizationCount} organization(s) found."
        return organizationCount
    }

}
```

Do i need to add an import statement? What do i need to add? Note that the class is located in src/groovy/org/utils. I know that the 'log' variable is accessible in controllers, services, etc. Not sure in 'src' classes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

In grails 3, the default logging system is logback. Simply adding the @Slf4j annotation to your src/groovy class will take care of things.

```
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

@Slf4j
class MyUtil {
```

Answer (score 7):

In Groovy 1.8, you may also annotate the class with `@Log` (for java.util.logging) or `@Log4j` (for log4j) and it will "magically" have a `log` property. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+1.8+release+notes#Groovy1.8releasenotes-@Log for details.

PS.: If you use java.util.logging the `log.debug`call will still fail because there's no `debug` method.

Answer (score 3):

The log variable is injected by grails and thus only available in the grails-specific classes like controllers, services, etc. - and I don't think you can "import" that in any way.

Outside these classes, you'll just have to use log4j "regularly", i.e.

```
Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class).debug()
```

Comment: thanks for the lead! unfortunately, i'm having issue on using 'debug' method. i'm having this exception:

Error: No signature of method: java.util.logging.Logger.debug() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [There are 15363 organization(s) found.]

however, when i tried 'info' level, everything's find. Here's the sample code:

String s = "There are ${organizationCount} organization(s) found."
Logger.getLogger(this.class.getName()).info(s)

Note that when i replace 'info' with 'debug', i'm having that exception.

Comment: @firnnauriel: looks like you're running into a problem with the overloaded debug method vs. groovy's type magic. Try building the string as a "traditional" Java string using +, instead of a GString.

Comment: You could also use Log4j, which will call toString() on the argument, so it doesn't matter if it's a GString or String. Just import org.apache.log4j.Logger instead of the JUL Logger.

Answer (score 0):

Log4j is one of the best logging for groovy

```
import groovy.util.logging.Log4j

@Log4j
public class MyClass{
//Use for logger check
public static void myMethod(){
    //log.error(null, "This is the log message", throwable)

    //log.error(null, "This is the log message", throwable)

    //log.info("This is the message for info")

    //log.debugg("This is the message for debugging")
}
}
```

***Log4j.properties***

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log =folderpath
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, R, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
# %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%C:%L [%t]  - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${log}/filename.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=2048KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern="%d %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"
# %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%C:%L [%t]  - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**Hope it will help you....**

Answer (score 0):

Well I have done this in grails 3.1.8 which uses Logback.

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

public class MyClass{

   static final LOG = LogFactory.getLog(this)

   def function(){
     LOG.debug "Debug message"
   }

   static staticFunction(){
     LOG.debug "Another debug message"
   }
}
```