# adding loggers to Grails classes

Tags: grails, logging, slf4j

I use the following approach to access a logger instance from classes in a Grails app:

In Grails artefacts (controllers, services, domain classes, etc.) I simply use the logger that is added by Grails, e.g.

```
class MyController {
  def someAction() {
    log.debug "something"
  }
}
```

For classes under `src/groovy` I annotate them with `@groovy.util.logging.Slf4j`, e.g.

```
@Slf4j
class Foo {

  Foo() {
    log.debug "log it"
  }
}
```

The logger seems to behave properly in both cases, but it slightly bothers me that the class of the loggers differs. When I use the annotation, the class of the logger is `org.slf4j.impl.GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter`, but when I use the logger that's automatically added to Grails artefacts the class is `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLog`.

Is there a recommended (or better) approach to adding loggers to Grails classes?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem with what you described. SLF4J isn't a logging framework, it's a logging framework wrapper. But aside from some Grails-specific hooks in the Grails class, they both implement the same interface and delegate eventually to the same loggers/appenders/etc. in the real  implementation library, typically Log4j.

What I'm pretty sure is different though is the log category/name, because you need to configure the underlying library based on what the logger names become. With annotations the logger name is the same as the full class name an package. With the one Grails adds, there's an extra prefix based on the artifact type. I always forget the naming convention but a quick way to know the logger name is to log it; add this in your class where it will be accessed at runtime:

```
println log.name
```

and it will print the full logger name (using `println` instead of a `log` method avoids potential misconfiguration issues that could keep the message from being logged

I like to keep things simple and consistent and know that being used, so I skip the wrapper libraries and use Log4j directly. Access the logger is easy. Import the class

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
```

and then add this as a class field:

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().name)
```

This can be copy/pasted to other classes since there's no hard-coded names. It won't work in static scope, so for that I'd add

```
static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(this.name)
```

which also avoids hard-coding by using Groovy's support for "this" in static scope to refer to the class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the @Log4j (for log4j) instead.

```
@Log4j (for log4j)
```

[How can i use 'log' inside a src/groovy/ class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577596/how-can-i-use-log-inside-a-src-groovy-class)